# Emit socket from a controller - How to get access to socket server from a controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

## Bases

I'm trying to use sockets on my node project. This is the how it basically works :

```
/
  |-> controllers/
  |  |-> home.js
  |-> app.js
  |-> sockets.js
```

**/app.js**

On app, I call sockets.js to start the socket server :

```
var express         = require('express');
var sockets         = require('./sockets');

var app = module.exports = express();

var server = app.listen(config.PORT);
var io = sockets(server);
```

**/sockets.js**

On this file I start the socket server, and return io.

```
var socket          = require('socket.io');

module.exports = function(server) {
  var io = socket.listen(server);

  io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
     // Here I can call every socket I want (if I have the socket_id) with this code : 
     var socket = io.to(socket_id);
     socket.emit('message', {});
  });

  return io;
};
```

## Question

But now, I want to retrieve my io server on my home controller and call a specific socket. I've tried to do this :

**/controller/home.js**

```
var io  = require('../sockets.js');

module.exports = {
  home: function(req, res, next) {
    var socket = io.to(socket_id);
    socket.emit('message', {});
  }
};
```

But I have this error, cause I don't execute the function (but I don't want create a new socket server here) :

```
TypeError: Object function (server) {
  var io = socket.listen(server);
  /*.....*/
  return io;
} has no method 'to'
```

I want to get an access to the io variable returned by this function called on app.js. How Can i get it ?

Comment: Are you using the `home.js` controller in your `app.js`?

Comment: Yeah `home.js` is called by my router when user ask for `/`

Answer (score 1):

You could convert `sockets.js` into an object that exposes your `io` property. You would also add a function `listen` that app.js calls during initialization.

**// sockets.js**

```
module.exports = {
    listen: function(server) {
        this.io = socket.listen(server);
        //...
        return this.io; 
    }
}
```

Your controller can then access `require('../sockets.js').io`, You just need to make sure `io` is defined at the time you use it, or otherwise make sure app.js calls `listen` before your controller gets invoked.

Answer (score 0):

You must be convert sockets.js into an object that exposes your io property. 
You would also add a function listen that app.js calls during initialization.

Your controller can then access require('../sockets.js').io.